# Api Authorization working in postman but not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I created an api with authorization, It is working correctly in postman but but i am not able to use authorization in flutter, I am getting Statuscode: 401(unauthorized) in flutter but in postman i am getting statuscode: 200(success). Here is my Code:

```
sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String Authorization =  sharedPreferences.getString("token"); 
    var data = await http.get("http://10.148.7.58/Election/api/TblDatas",
        headers: <String, String>{'Authorization': '$Authorization',}
    );



 //Also tried these
    //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '$Authorization',}
    //headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "$Authorization"}
   
    print('status code is' + (data.statusCode).toString());
```

Comment: may be your authenticaiton is method bearer token? 
can you also add the postman curl command to the question?

Comment: @MuratAslan   i selected GET in the request type, then i select TYPE= "bearer Token" from dropdown under the AUTHORIZATION tab..... and type the token in the token text box

Comment: if its a bearer token, you must send the token with "Bearer " prefix; {"Authorization":"Bearer $token"}. btw you can use the postman dart code generator to compare with yours

Comment: @MuratAslan  got this in postman:                                                                               
 `code` curl --location --request GET '10.148.7.58/Election/api/TblDatas' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjEiLCJuYmYiOjE2MDUyNDM1MjUsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQxNjMyNSwiaWF0IjoxNjA1MjQzNTI1fQ.ffuF_B22nHhe76zdi6Y32C8yg7yZ2uCQKqnoNlDp5y8' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
        "name": "SharmaRahul",
        "mobile": "9086369404",
        "password": "rahul"

}'   `code`

Comment: See my answer to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/72789318/11445944

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json', //add context-type
  'Accept': 'application/json',//add accept
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
 }
```

Comment: Already had used this option but its not working, I am strucked at this point for the last 2-3 days.  any solution other than this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server accepts lower case header names - in this case authorization, as Dart will lower case them. This fools some servers that aren't RFC compliant