# Flutter DIO Unauthorized I/flutter ( 3668): 401

Tags: json, flutter, http, dio

Hello community I have one question I have been trying it for hours I couldn't solve it and have been sending post request to server with Authorization in flutter using DIO library on postman it works like charm but in flutter always it give **

> 401 unauthorized

**

here is my code

```
try {
      Response response =
      await Dio().post("https://somewebsite.com/public/api/addprod",
        data: data,
        options: Options(
            headers: {
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8;application/json;multipart/form-data',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              "Authorization": "Bearer " +token!

        },
            followRedirects: false,
            validateStatus: (status) {
              return status! < 500; }
        ),
      );
```

here is my postMan image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That issue was caused by your server not accepting the lower header name. Yes, `http` will convert your header name to lower case since `http 2.8`. And dio use `http` in it's package.

In `http.dart` docummentation :

> Header names are converted to lower-case unless [preserveHeaderCase] is set to true. If two header names are the same when converted to lower-case, they are considered to be the same header, with one set of values.

How to solve it?

**Option 1 (Back-end/REST API)**

Make sure your server accept lower case header name.
Because dart will convert this header

```
{
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
   'Authorization': '$token',
}
```

to lower-case header name

```
{
   'accept': 'application/json',
   'connection': 'keep-alive',
   'authorization': '$token',
}
```

**Option 2 (Flutter)**

Follow this step:

1. Find `io_adapter.dart` in *External Libraries->Dart Packages->dio-4.06->src->adapters->io_adapter.dart*
2. Find this code inside `io_adapter.dart`

```
//Set Headers
options.headers.forEach((k, v) {
   if (v != null) request.headers.set(k, '$v');
});
```

3. Add `preserveHeaderCase: true`

```
//Set Headers
options.headers.forEach((k, v) {
   if (v != null) request.headers.set(k, '$v',preserveHeaderCase: true);
});
```

4. Clean your project and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You should define `onError` method:

```dart
onError: (DioError e, handler) async {
  if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {

    final user = Hive.box<UserTable>('user');
    String refreshToken = '';
    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      refreshToken = user.get(0)!.accessToken;
    }

    e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $refreshToken';
    
    return handler.resolve(await dio.fetch(e.requestOptions));
  }
  return handler.next(e);
},
```