# Facing some issues in Flutter REST API using with JWT token

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, jwt

I'm facing some issues in Flutter REST API using with JWT token

Here the header authentication was not passing properly. But it working good in Postman

```
**Example Code:**

    String url = "project URL";
    String token = "generated jwt token";

    var headers = {
      'Authorization': token,
      'Cookie': 'ci_session=u17u9effeqk5fdhl1eqdh4jsmu3o3v29'
    };
    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

If I try without the JWT token by removing it in the backend it's working properly. But I need to work with JWT.

Can anyone please help to fix this issue?

Comment: This issue was caused `http` library convert your header name to lower case. See my answer to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/72789318/11445944

Answer (score 0):

I use dio package to work with the same...

```
// Import dio package

Future<void> function() async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    String url = 'example.com';
    
     try {
      final response = await dio.post(
        url,
        options: Options(
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $userToken'}, //This is where you define your header and provide jwt token
        ),
      );
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      if (error.response!.statusCode == 401) {
        print(error.response.toString());
        throw Error();
      }
      print(error);
      throw Error();
    }
  }
}
```

The package can be found here https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Feel free to clear up any confusions

Comment: Thanks for your response Novice Coder, but still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you describe the error you are facing? A picture or the error text you get in your debug console

Comment: The response is still showing like this,   {"status":false,"message":"Unauthorize token"}, but it is working in postman

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue here is the value that you give in your header.

For Bearer tokens, the value given in the Authorization header must be `Bearer`  followed by the value of your token. If you did not implement some specific/homemade authorisation function in your backend, this must be what is expected to be received.

Try replacing `'Authorization': token,` by

```dart
'Authorization': `Bearer $token`,
```

and it shouldd work as intended.

Comment: Thank you, but still facing the same issue.